# Active Hard Drive Protection?

Tags: hard-drive

Does Ubuntu include any sort of Active Hard Drive Protection? (also know as active protection system APS).

Or any software that parks the hard drive heads when a fall is detected or with sudden acceleration.

(Example: [ThinkVantage Active Protection System](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/ht037696) )

Answer (score 1):

See: http://www.thinkwiki.org

Ubuntu packages:

```
hdapsd - HDAPS daemon for various laptops with motion sensors
tp-smapi-dkms - ThinkPad hardware/firmware access modules source - dkms version
```

**`hdapsd`** : [List of supported Thinkpads](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Tp_smapi#Model-specific_status) | [GitHub Sources](https://github.com/evgeni/hdapsd#systemd-and-udev-integration:Link)
**`tp_smapi`**: Homepage is [ThinkPad Configuration Tools for Linux](http://tpctl.sourceforge.net/)